# Sequencing of elements in dict python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a dictionary of elements:

```
leveldict = {
    (3, 2): (3,), (1, 2, 4): (1, 2), (2, 4, 3): (2, 4), (1, 4): (1,),
    (4,): (), (3, 4, 1): (3, 4), (4, 3): (4,), (2, 3, 1): (2, 3),
    (2, 4): (2,), (1, 2, 3, 4): (1, 2, 3)
}
```

I want to find all the sequences of key-value pairs in `leveldict`, where the key of the next sequence item is the value from the previous sequence item. The order of the items in each tuple is *not* significant.

Here is my expected output for the data given above:

```
s1 = ((1, 2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 3)), ((2, 3, 1), (2, 3)), ((3, 2), (3,))
s2 = ((1, 2, 4), (1, 2))
s3 = ((2, 4, 3), (2, 4)), ((2, 4), (2,))
s4 = ((3, 4, 1), (3, 4)), ((4, 3), (4,)), ((4,), ())
s5 = ((1, 4), (1,))
```

Note: The elements in `leveldict` are guaranteed to form sequences like this.

Comment: You only described about your requirements. What you tried so far ?

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I'm not able to understand what you're trying to do or how to obtain the expected output.

Comment: @Rawing It's a dictionary hiding multiple linked lists.

Comment: Oh, I think I get it. But what would the expected output for `{(1,2): (3,4), (3,4): (5,), (4,3): (6,)}` be? Can that ever happen?

Comment: Hey @RahulKP for finding similarity in among tuple elements i can use jaccard_similarity concept, however the problem is not with finding similarity   but how to iterate over dict recursively until to form a sequence.

Comment: Hey @Rawing this `{(1,2): (3,4), (3,4): (5,), (4,3): (6,)}` can never happen, their will always be  sequence, say value tuple elements one item in dict will be in key tuple of other item in dict. e.g: `{(1,2,3): (2,3), (2,3): (3,), (3): ()}`

Comment: @Rawing I think you'll find the question rather easier to understand now. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We want to ignore the order inside each of the key and value tuples, so it makes sense to convert them to sets. But we want to use them as dict keys, so we need to use frozensets, since normal sets aren't hashable. And we can put them into an OrderedDict to make it easier to start each sequence with the longest keys.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

leveldict = {
    (3, 2): (3,), (1, 2, 4): (1, 2), (2, 4, 3): (2, 4), (1, 4): (1,), 
    (4,): (), (3, 4, 1): (3, 4), (4, 3): (4,), (2, 3, 1): (2, 3), 
    (2, 4): (2,), (1, 2, 3, 4): (1, 2, 3)
}

# Store in an OrderedDict of frozensets, ordered by length
a = [(frozenset(k), frozenset(v)) for k,v in leveldict.items()]
a.sort(key=lambda t:(len(t[0]), len(t[1]))) 
odict = OrderedDict(a)

def unfreeze(k, v):
    return tuple(k), tuple(v)

all_seqs = []
while odict:
    k, v = odict.popitem()
    seq = [unfreeze(k, v)]
    k = v
    while k in odict:
        v = odict.pop(k)
        seq.append(unfreeze(k, v))
        k = v

    all_seqs.append(seq)

# Perform a simple numeric sort on the tuple sequences
all_seqs.sort()
for row in all_seqs:
    print(row)
```

**output**

```
[((1, 2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 3)), ((1, 2, 3), (2, 3)), ((2, 3), (3,))]
[((1, 2, 4), (1, 2))]
[((1, 3, 4), (3, 4)), ((3, 4), (4,)), ((4,), ())]
[((1, 4), (1,))]
[((2, 3, 4), (2, 4)), ((2, 4), (2,))]
```

The strategy here is to simply pop the longest remaining key from `odict`, and search for key - value chains.

Comment: Yes order of elements is not an issue, thank you for the answer it work's  :)